# Переход по неделям по нажатию на кнопки

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Как сделать навигацию по неделям как на скриншоте? Нажимаем вперёд переключаемся на следующую неделю, если назад то на предыдущую?

При этом нужно в переменные `m1 и m2` записывать `timestamp` первого дня недели без учета времени и последнего дня недели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен объект `Calendar`. Устанавливаете ему часовой пояс. Изначально время будет текущее, потом указываете время по нулям и день недели первый.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Вот у нас есть нижняя граница. Методом `c.getTime()` можете получить нужный вам timestapm(ну, если миллисекунды откинуть)

Чтобы получить верхнюю - делаем `c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1)`, получаем верхнюю границу. Аналогично смещаем обе границы вверх/вниз при листании

Comment: При c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1) я получаю первый день следующей недели, а как мне получать последний день недели? Т.е. в c.getTime() я получил понедельник текущей недели допустим, а воскресенье не знаю как получить.

Comment: делаете c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1), затем c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1), получаете начало воскресения

Comment: Спасибо! Думаю аналогичным образом попробую сделать период за месяц, год

Comment: Не могу догнать, а как сделать переход к предыдущей неделе. Вместо calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1); пишу calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1); Первый день текущей недели 16.12.2019, если прописать -1 то выводит 09.12.2019 - правильно, но вот последний день (воскресенье) предыдущей недели выводит некорректно. Вместо 15.12.2019 выводит 01.12.2019

Comment: Покажите код, мне кажется у вас проблема с тем что вы один и тот же календарь пытаетесь для разных концов использовать. Это, видимо, в новый вопрос надо писать, т.к. это уже другая проблема

Comment: Я создавал новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061312/. Там приведу весь код, который получился