# Получить следующую и предыдущую неделю в календаре

Tags: java, android

Есть активити с двумя кнопками `Prev` и `Next` и `TextView`.

По нажатию на Prev в TextView нужно выводить предыдущую неделю (понедельник - воскресенье даты). Например 09.12.2019 - 15.12.2019, а по нажатию на Next наоборот следующую неделю 23.12.2019 - 29.12.2019. Как это реализовать?

Вот весь код:

```
public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    private Button btnPrev;
    private Button btnNext;
    private TextView txtPeriod;
    private TextView txtMills;

    private boolean isCurrentDate = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        btnPrev = findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        txtPeriod = findViewById(R.id.txtPeriod);
        txtMills = findViewById(R.id.txtMills);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setWeekNext();

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            setWeekNext();
        });

        btnPrev.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            setWeekPrev();
        });
    }

    //Вывод предыдущей недели
    private void setWeekPrev() {

        if (!isCurrentDate) {
            calendar.setTime(new Date());
            isCurrentDate = true;
        }

        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); //Устанавливаем понедельник первым днем недели
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //Устанавливаем часы в ноль
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); //минуты в ноль
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); //секкунды в ноль
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); //миллисекунды в ноль

        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1); //Предыдущая неделя

        long mills1 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

        txtPeriod.setText(calendar.getTime() + " ");

        txtMills.setText(mills1 + " / ");

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);

        txtPeriod.append(calendar.getTime() + "");

        long mills2 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -6);

        txtMills.append(mills2 + "");
    }

    //Вывод следующей недели
    private void setWeekNext() {

        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); //Устанавливаем понедельник первым днем недели
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //Устанавливаем часы в ноль
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); //минуты в ноль
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); //секкунды в ноль
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); //миллисекунды в ноль

        long mills1 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

        txtPeriod.setText(calendar.getTime() + " ");

        txtMills.setText(mills1 + " / ");

        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1); //Следующая неделя
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1); //Предыдущий день. (т.е. воскресенье)

        txtPeriod.append(calendar.getTime() + "");

        long mills2 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

        txtMills.append(mills2 + "");
    }

}
```

В итоге я бы хотел получить следующее:

1. При нажатии на `btnNext` получаем понедельник и воскресенье следующей недели
2. При нажатии на `btnPrev` получаем понедельник и воскресенье предыдущей недели

и так по нарастающей или по убывающей смотря какую кнопку нажали.

В `mills1` и `mills2` соответственно записываются `timestamp` понедельника и воскресенья недели.

Answer (score 1):

Второй параметр в методе `add()` может принимать отрицательные значения.

```
calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1); // переход на предыдущую неделю
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно. Мой код выше выводит в TextView такое значение. Сегодня 21.12.2019 и этот код выводит такое 16.12.1019 - 22.12.2019, т.е. дату понедельника и воскресенья текущей недели. Когда нажимаю Next этот же код выведет 23.12.2019 - 29.12.2019. А как мне сделать так, чтобы когда я нажму Prev выводилось 09.12.2019 - 15.12.2019, если еще раз нажму Prev выводилось 02.12.2019 - 08.12.2019 и т.д.

Comment: На Next у вас повешено 1, на Prev повесьте -1.